# How to compare annotations by two groups?

Tags: statistical-significance, fishers-exact-test, coefficient-of-variation

I have two groups of test persons that manually created multiple annotations for different underlying, unknown values (each person created multiple annotations). I'd like to find a statistical test that tells me with a given confidence level that the annotations by the two groups are of the same quality. Quality being expressed in terms of the variance of their annotations.

(Artificial) examples for annotations:

```
Annotation by person1: {100, 101, 99, 98, 100, 101}
Annotation by person1: {50, 49, 49, 49, 50, 51}
Annotation by person2: {12, 12, 13, 12}
...
```

To compare the series individually, one can use the [Coefficient of Variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation), i.e. $c_v=\frac{\sigma}{\mu}$. This addresses the fact that the series all have different means and describe different true values. And to compare two $c_v$ one can use the [Asymptotic test for the equality of coefficients of variation from k populations (Feltz and Miller 1996)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/249525/17577).

But how do I test for equality of *many* (hundreds) time series (each with a different mean, but similar $c_v$) from *two groups*? What I really want to test is the equality of the annotations by *group*.

What if I simply compute the $c_v$ for all series and treat these $c_v$-values as two distributions. One for `group1` and one for `group2`. I could test for significant differences in these two distributions using [t test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test). Would this approach allow me to judge with confidence whether the annotations by members of the two groups are of equal quality?

If not, can you suggest a better approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the annotators working on the same work items?

Comment: Some items may be identical, others won't. For each item, an annotator will produce multiple annotations, as shown in the example.

Comment: You may want to read this paper http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/Q14-1025 on the probabilistic approach. There are other models that estimate worker reliability and item difficulty (difficulty-ability models). I have some simple implementations in C#. This requires some familiarity with Bayesian statistics, graphical models in particular.

Comment: Thank you. What about the much simpler t-test approach I outlined. Will that produce respectable results?